# C# Windows UWP Use Sidewalk in Routes

Tags: c#, routes, navigation, uwp

I want to create an application for displaying a walking route with the
`GetWalkingRouteFromWaypointsAsync();` method.
That works fine for me, but I cannot use the sidewalks which were displayed on Bing Maps. The method is not using them. 
Is there a way to use them into my application?

```
MapRouteFinderResult routeResult =
  await MapRouteFinder.GetWalkingRouteFromWaypointsAsync(waypoints);
  if (routeResult.Status == MapRouteFinderStatus.Success)
  {
    // Use the route to initialize a MapRouteView.
    MapRouteView viewOfRoute = new MapRouteView(routeResult.Route);
    viewOfRoute.RouteColor = Colors.Yellow;
    viewOfRoute.OutlineColor = Colors.Black;
    double dis = routeResult.Route.LengthInMeters / 1000;
    distance.Text = dis.ToString() + " km";
    // Add the new MapRouteView to the Routes collection
    // of the MapControl.
    RouteMap.Routes.Add(viewOfRoute);

    // Fit the MapControl to the route.
    await RouteMap.TrySetViewBoundsAsync(
          routeResult.Route.BoundingBox, null,
          Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapAnimationKind.None);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I know how to solve the problem.
If there are not enough waypoints you can`t use the sidewalks and the route will be generated near to the streets, but if there more points while walking on the sidewalk it works.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/windows/apps/mt219701.aspx): *You must specify a maps authentication key before you can use map services. For more info, see Request a maps authentication key.*

This is for security reasons, and therefore you must make your universal windows app authenticated.

if you want the specify a authentication key in your app: [Click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/windows/apps/mt219694.aspx)

Comment: I use the key, but i haven`t shown it into the code because I thaught that it isn`t important.